# mysql cdc transaction grouping

Tags: apache-flink

I tried mysql cdc days, it works well but I cannot find anything usefull about transaction info.

I use DataStream API to connect and read mysql binlog. I can find all change log at the end if one table is wrote/deleted/updated, bug I cannot get the transaction id of that.

I need to group the change log by group, to update something atomicly; if without the group action, processing change log event one by one, the Atomicity and consistency is broken, and the result goes wrong.
The version of flink-connector-mysql-cdc I use is 2.3.0, in scala language.

Here is the code.

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON
import com.ververica.cdc.connectors.mysql.source.MySqlSource
import com.ververica.cdc.debezium.JsonDebeziumDeserializationSchema
import io.debezium.data.Envelope
import io.github.streamingwithflink.bosser.broadcast_test.RandomPartitioner
import io.github.streamingwithflink.util.SimpleLogger
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichMapFunction
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.{CheckpointingMode, TimeCharacteristic}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

import scala.tools.nsc.doc.html.page.JSONObject
import scala.util.Random

/** Object that defines the DataStream program in the main() method */
object AverageSensorReadings {

    val tb_name = "cdc_test"
    type stream_type = String

    /** main() defines and executes the DataStream program */
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
//        val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
        val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = {
            val conf = new Configuration()
            conf.setInteger("rest.port", 9981)
            conf.setString("state.savepoints.dir", "file:///workplace/idea-scala/flink-mvn-test/data/savepoint")
//            conf.setString("execution.savepoint.path", "file:///workplace/idea-scala/flink-mvn-test/data/savepoint/savepoint-a0de9e-32a700b9e770")
            StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(conf)
        }
        // use event time for the application
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
        // configure watermark interval
        env.getConfig
            .setParallelism(4)

        env.enableCheckpointing(interval = 1000 * 10, mode = CheckpointingMode.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointStorage("file:///workplace/idea-scala/flink-mvn-test/data/checkpoint")

        SimpleLogger.info(s"checkpointConf: ${env.getCheckpointConfig}")

        val dbSource: MySqlSource[stream_type] = MySqlSource.builder[stream_type]()
            .hostname(Conf.db_host)
            .port(Conf.db_port)
            .username(Conf.db_username)
            .password(Conf.db_password)
            .databaseList(Conf.db_name)
            .tableList(Conf.db_name + "." + tb_name)
            .serverTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai")
            .includeSchemaChanges(true)
            .deserializer(new JsonDebeziumDeserializationSchema())
            .build()

        Envelope.Operation.CREATE

        val inputStream: DataStream[stream_type] = env.fromSource(dbSource, watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), sourceName = "db").setParallelism(1)
            .partitionCustom(RandomPartitioner[stream_type], e=>e)

        var stream = inputStream.map(new RichMapFunction[stream_type, JsonDebezium] {
            override def map(in: stream_type) = {
                SimpleLogger.info(s"got rec: $in")
                in
                val jsonDebezium: JsonDebezium = JSON.toJavaObject(JSON.parseObject(in), classOf[JsonDebezium])
                SimpleLogger.info(s"rec obj: ${jsonDebezium.toJsonString}")
                jsonDebezium
            }
        })

        stream.addSink(new SinkFunction[JsonDebezium] {})

        // execute application
        env.execute(s"test of ${this.getClass}")
    }

}
```

Oh god, anyone help me?